# display grid align items center no funciona bien en Chrome

Tags: css-grid-layout

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy utilizando un container con `display grid - align items center` para alinear el contenido de forma vertical.

El contenido a su vez es un contenedor que a su vez utiliza `display flex` para organizar de forma horizontal o vertical otros `divs` dependiendo del dispositivo y orientación.

El asunto es que en Firefox funciona muy bien y en Chrome no muy bien. Sobretodo en dispositivos moviles.
De hecho es una sección en particular, de cuatro secciones falla solo en una y eso es lo más raro.

Es como si el contenido de esa sección no respete los límites de mi padding y genere overflow.

De momento, la única manera de solucionarlo fue agregando un `max-width` a mi contenido al cual lo tengo que setear en un 60% del contentedor  y luego volverlo a 100% con una mediaquery, pero no creo que esa sea la solución.

El proyecto lo tengo hosteado en un Netlify para hacer pruebas por si lo quieren ver https://tonyupdate.netlify.app/

La sección que genera el problema es "ABOUT" luego si ven, las demás secciones con tienen el mismo problema.

```
header{
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 37% center;
    height: 100%;    
}

.flexbox-container{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!
Por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema, la solución fue muy sencilla por cierto!
Simplemente he agregado grid-template-columns: 100%; a mi grid container.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)